# simple join in Snowflake error on join clause

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm joining two tables in the same schema on a column (for which I've confirmed the syntax and data type to be the same in both tables) and am getting the following error:

```
SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 117 invalid identifier 'EFI.FIRMID'
```

This is the query generating the above error:

```
SELECT top 10 * FROM TAXACT_EDW_RAW_PRD.PREPONLINE.EFININFO AS efi JOIN TAXACT_EDW_RAW_PRD.PREPONLINE.FIRMINFO fi ON efi.firmid = fi.firmid
```

I really don't understand why this isn't working? This should just be a simple join...

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Without seeing your actual table definition is difficult to diagnose, but are you sure that the case of your field names in your table are correct?  If the table was created with double-quotes around the field names, then case must be maintained when referencing the field names.

Comment: Can you check if the column FIRMID exists in the table EFININFO , you can just do a SELECT FIRMID from TAXACT_EDW_RAW_PRD.PREPONLINE.EFININFO.

Comment: Without description of the table I'm proposing to close it as a typo. The most likely explanation is the referenced column does not exist because the OP has made a typo.

Comment: "firmid" is not in the table "TAXACT_EDW_RAW_PRD.PREPONLINE.EFININFO"

Answer (score 1):

This error pops only when column does not exists and reproduced same error when pulling non existing column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

so with the below SQL, we can see the this query works when the columns are present:

```
WITH table1(firmid) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
), table2(firmid) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (2),(4),(6)
)
SELECT top 10 * FROM table1 AS efi JOIN table2 fi ON efi.firmid = fi.firmid;
```

| FIRMID | FIRMID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |

now we change the first column to something that does not exist:

```
SELECT top 10 * FROM table1 AS efi JOIN table2 fi ON efi.firmidx = fi.firmid;
```

> SQL compilation error: error line 6 at position 53 invalid identifier 'EFI.FIRMIDX'

which is the token that starts at 53.

Now let's change the first back to good and the second to bad:

```
SELECT top 10 * FROM table1 AS efi JOIN table2 fi ON efi.firmid = fi.firmidx;
```

> SQL compilation error: error line 6 at position 66 invalid identifier 'FI.FIRMIDX'

This shows us, the column of the error message can be trusted. Therefore your `efi` (`FROM TAXACT_EDW_RAW_PRD.PREPONLINE.EFININFO`) table does not have a column called `FIRMID`